# Permutations without repeats

Tags: permutations

Consider this matrix:

```
A B C D E
D C A E B
B A E C D
E D B A C
C E D B A
```

The letters are arranged so that no row and no coulumn contains the same letter twice (Sudoku style).

Let's call the number of diffent letters $n$ (5 in the above example). When writing the first row, I have $n!$ permutations to choose from.

How many permutations can I choose between when writing the second row? And the third row? Etc.

Comment: It's a latin square!

Comment: You may be interested in https://oeis.org/A002860 which tabulates (with references and links) the number of Latin squares of order $n$.

Comment: Find anything useful at that link, oz1cz?

Comment: I haven't studied it in detail yet, Gerry.

Comment: OK, take your time. If you want to be sure I see a comment, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When entering the second row, it has to be a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the first row. When $n=5$ there are $44$ derangements. But from the third row onwards
the number of possibilities will depend on exactly what the previous rows
contain.